# Generic condition for vector fields/normal sections

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $(M,g)$ be a riemannian manifold, and $S\subset M$ a submanifold. I would like to know if there is a result which states that, for some hypothesis about the codimension of $S$, the property for a vector field $X\in\mathcal{T}(M)$ to being nowhere tangent to $S$ is generic.

Writing, for $p\in S$, the orthogonal decomposition $T_pM=T_pS\oplus N_pS$, and $f_X:S\to NS$ defined by $f_X(p)=(X_p)^\perp$, the property can be rewrited as $f_X^{-1}(0_{NS})=\varnothing$, the latter being equivalent to $f_X\pitchfork 0_{NS}$ iff $\dim S-\mathrm{codim}\,0_{NS}<0$, i.e. $2\dim S<\dim M$. Since transversality is a generic property, a generic vector field is nowhere tangent to $S$ if $2\dim S<\dim M$.

I would like to know if this kind of reasoning is correct, and if this result is true we can actually find sharper bounds for the inequality. Thank you!

Comment: take $M=\mathbb{R}^4$ with coordinates $(x,y,z,w)$ and $S=\lbrace 0 \rbrace \times \mathbb{R}^3$. Then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is nowhere tangent but $2$dim$S=6>$dim$M=4$

Comment: @Baol: Indeed, but I think it does not make the property generic: in your setup, no small perturbation of a vector field which takes both values $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $-\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ will be nowhere tangent (since the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ coordinate still has to vanish somewhere).

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ is not a coordinate ! Is a map $:M \rightarrow TM: p \mapsto \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right|_p T_pM$.

Comment: @Baol: Yes, by coordinate I wanted to say the coordinate $\alpha$ in front of $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ that we get writing $X=\alpha^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$.

Comment: ok but I took $(\alpha^1,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4)=(1,0,0,0)$

Comment: @Baol: By genericity, I mean that if we take any vector field, a small perturbation can ensures the property. I agree that your example checks the property, but that won't be true for all vector fields (ex: $(\alpha^1,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\alpha^4)=(\arctan(x),0,0,0)$).